# Application of synthetic division by second degree polynomials.

Tags: complex-numbers

Exercise: Use synthetic division rather than DeMoivre's Theorem to find $(2-i)^7$. Then given $z=2-i$ use synthetic division to find $2z^3-7z^2+5z-3$.

Answer (score 2):

If one finds the remainder $R(z)$ when $F(z)=z^7$ is divided by

\begin{equation}
[z-(2-i)]\cdot[z-(2+i)]=z^2-4z+5
\end{equation}

one finds that

\begin{equation}
F(z)=(z^2-4z+5)Q(z)+R(z)
\end{equation}

so

\begin{equation}
F(2-i)=(2-i)^7=0\cdot Q(2-i)+R(2-i)=-278+29i
\end{equation}

For 
\begin{equation}
F(z)=(2z^3-7z^2+5z-3)=(z^2-4z+5)Q(z)+R(z)\\
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
R(z)=-i-8\\
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
F(z)=(z^2-4z+5)Q(z)+R(z)\\
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
F(2-i)=0\cdot Q(2-i)-(2-i)-8=-10+i
\end{equation}

Comment: After $F(z)$ in second line: $-4z$ or $-5z$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, everywhere I wrote $z^2-5x+5$ it should be $z^2-4z+5$. Thank you for catching that mistake. The remainders are correct, however since I actually used $z^2-4z+5$ in the calculation.